# NEAT Neuronal network JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, neural-network, neat, tetris

I started to learn a bit about neuronal networks I wanted to create a neuronal network which learns to play tetris.

So I stumbled across [NEAT JS Library](https://github.com/hardmaru/backprop-neat-js)
and hooked it up with a console tetris game in nodejs.
My concern is that something is wrong because the network keeps mashing just one button regardless on how many tiles are already on the screen. Not sure if I wrote a not correct fitness function or my trainer is dropping my best genome. Because when the network scores some points by accelerating the tile down, that behavior is gone in the next generation.

Help is always appreciated :-) if you want to have a look check out the [repo](https://github.com/DomHey/NEAT-tetris)

To run it just cd into the dir and run index.js with node.js

Thanks to all in advance !

Comment: This is probably too broad as asked, and doesn't provide any immediately actionable information.

Comment: Ok then let me rephrase my question. Why does the network not seem do differ its choices based on the state of the game field.  It seems to decide for just one button and never tries a second one the whole game.

Comment: To rephrase what you're asking: "Please read and understand my codebase and debug it." That's actually a really hard thing to do.

Comment: Hey, you might want to check out my implenetation of NEAT in js https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic. It's more user-freindly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things...

1. Test if you got your scoring function right. Try to change it to reward something stupid like placeing blocks on the very left. If you get the expected behaviour you can probably easily change the function to fit your problem. If the result is the opposite of what you expected you might be telling the algorithm about the **error** instead of the score, so multiply the value with -1 before returning it.
2. Keep track of average scores per generation and see if they get better over time. If yes, everything is fine but you probably need more training time. If not something in the algorithm is wrong.
3. Check your evolution parameters. You should have a as big as possible population to ensure variety. about 200 should be the minimum. Use the best 10% of your population to reproduce. every reproduced genome should have a small (something like 3%) chance to mutate.